# Issue to install charlock_holmes_bundle_icu -v '0.6.9.2'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I try to install the gem `charlock_holmes_bundle_icu -v '0.6.9.2'`
but I receive this error:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>
> ERROR:  Error installing charlock_holmes_bundle_icu:
>
> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    current directory: /Users/agatheloubert/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/charlock_holmes_bundle_icu-0.6.9.2/ext/charlock_holmes
/Users/agatheloubert/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180306-35008-vbolm2.rb extconf.rb
  -- tar zxvf icu4c-49_1_2-src.tgz
  -- LDFLAGS= CXXFLAGS="-O2 -fPIC" CFLAGS="-O2 -fPIC" ./configure --prefix=/Users/agatheloubert/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/charlock_holmes_bundle_icu-0.6.9.2/ext/charlock_holmes/dst/ --disable-tests --disable-samples --disable-icuio --disable-extras --disable-layout --enable-static --disable-shared
  -- make install
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/agatheloubert/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
extconf.rb:7:in `sys': make install failed, please report issue on http://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes (RuntimeError)
    from extconf.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:31:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:31:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:27:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:27:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/agatheloubert/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/charlock_holmes_bundle_icu-0.6.9.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/agatheloubert/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.4.0-static/charlock_holmes_bundle_icu-0.6.9.2/gem_make.out
```

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I am also facing the same. Did find any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling and reinstalling solved the issue for me.

```
gem uninstall charlock_holmes
gem install charlock_holmes  --  --with-icu-dir=/usr/local/Custom/icu
```

You can use `sudo` for `su` permissions.